# What is the difference between a Facebook Canvas and Facebook Web project?

Tags: html-canvas, facebook, cocos2d-x-js

I am making a game on cocos2d-JS for Facebook. What is the difference between Facebook Canvas & Facebook Web project. From what I can tell, Facebook Canvas ask for the secure url and Web ask for the site URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Canvas app are apps that live inside the facebook eco-system. This is done by Facebook creating an iFrame to the canvas URL you supply. The authentication system is a POST variable sent one time when the "Facebook APP" is opened.

Facebook Web project app are apps that access the Facebook API and do not leave in the Facebook eco-system. You would have to authenticate the user differently than with the POST method in the example of a Facebook App.

In the past I have created Facebook Web Projects using the same url as the Facebook Canvas URL in order to provide identical experience ( minus some style and menu changes ) for users coming to the site and users installing the Facebook app.